# Add a suffix to "back" button url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site , where i need visitors to jump between theme previews. To see one of theme's preview i simply add a suffix of /?preview_theme_id=39393-023 to url. But further site viewing is continued in that theme preview mode. It's easy to escape if visitor clicks on link (add another suffix), but if visitor clicks "back" button in browser site stays in that same theme preview mode. Is there any way to add that suffix to an event where visitor clicks "back"?

Comment: Never worked with it so cant give you an example, but take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: good place to start. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing isn't possible.  When the user hits the back button they are turning the window.history object to a previous value, but you cannot change these values as far as I know.

Even if you could however, the back button does not cause a new request to be sent to the server, therefore your appended URL query wouldn't be applied when the user hit back anyways.